# Why do I need resolveexternals set to false?

Tags: xml

I am using `MSXML3` and have loaded an xml document which is a HTML page.
I found that if I do not set the `resolveExternals` property to false (and `validateOnParse` to `false`), I get the following error:

"The server did not understand the request, or the request was invalid.'
'Error processing resource 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'.'

Can anyone explain why I need `resolveExternals` set to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser is most likely trying to load that resource (the `.dtd`) from the remote site `w3.org`, and failing. Do you have a net connection from that process (perhaps with appropriate proxy configuration) ?

You should be able to specify a local copy of the `.dtd` to load instead if you don't want your process to load this remotely (usually a good idea).

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply. I have a net connection so that is not it. Doing some more research, if I try to validate the document with validateOnParse = true (resolveexternals=true), I get the error "Validate failed because the document does not contain exactly one root node". The document has the structure:
 '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
'<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
'<head> etc....

From what I understand, it should get the DTD and validate it.
Any ideas?

Thanks.
JD.

Comment: Just tested with AltovaXML 1.0 and validating the document seems to be fine without giving any sort of errors.